# Dart/Flutter: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Search'

Tags: flutter, dart

Dart/Flutter: I have a class which is fetching data from a server and returning a list but ListView.builder is throwing the error: The getter 'length' isn't defined for the type 'Search'.

**Here is the code of Search Class: **

```
class Search {
  String query;
  Search(query) {
    this.query = query;
    HttpClient()
        .getUrl(Uri.parse('https://api-request-url/search'))
        .then((request) => request.close())
        .then((response) async {
          response.transform(Utf8Decoder()).listen((event) {
            return event;
          });
        }
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Lets see the ListView() code please

Answer (score 0):

You aren't assigning returning `event` to anything.

Your class `Search` doesn't contain any `iterable` variable. Length of what exactly you want to get?

Comment: how can i do that?